# why $filter didn't work in consumption usage details Rest API?

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api, cost-management

Why consumption rest api parameter $filter didn't work? When I use this parameter expression $filter = properties/reservationId eq 'xxxx' but return result didn't contain reservationId ='xxxx'. here is my get request url:

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xyz/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$filter=properties/reservationId
> eq 'xxx'&metric=amortizedcost&api-version=2023-03-01